# What field does the Featured tab sort by?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I would imagine it would sort by time left on bounty or amount of bounty but it doesn't seem to do either.

What is this tab sorting by and is there anyway to sort by bounty amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sorted by the time until the bounty expires, so the question with the shortest time until the deadline is at the top of the list.